# An Interesting sequence Problem From Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We Define a sequence $x_n$ as follows:

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{(p-1)(x_n^p)+a}{px_n^{p-1}}$$

where $x_1 > \sqrt {a} $

For p = 2 the question becomes relatively easy:

as we have the following
for n = 1; we have $x_1 > \sqrt {a} $

Assume that we have $x_n > \sqrt{a}$

$$x_{n+1} - \sqrt{a}= \frac{x_n^2+a-2x_n\sqrt{a}}{2x_n} = \frac{(\sqrt{x_n}- \sqrt{a})^2}{2x_n} > 0 $$

so we have $x_{n+1}> \sqrt{a}$ => $x_n >\sqrt{a}$ for all n.

which would further imply that:

$$ x_{n+1} - x_n= \frac{a-x_n^2}{2x_n} < 0$$

so, we have a monotone bounded sequence that should converge to $\sqrt{a}$ (Using our lemma and the fact that ($|x_{n+1}-x_n| < \epsilon$ due to monotone convergence.)

however, we no longer have that nice quadratic simplification to prove $x_n> \sqrt{a}$ for all a.

do you guys have any idea how to proceed, I tried to follow a similar approach but was stuck with the inequalities.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1276534/42969, that is simply the Newton-Raphson method to find the solution of $x^p = a$.